# Replacing a RAID controller, will the stored cache be synced to the wrong array?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

It's a generic question, but when you use a used RAID controller as replacement, does the controller verify the correct arrays are present before syncing the stored cache?

Battery-backed cache may not last that long, but nowadays with supercaps and flash, this is an important issue.

Comment: This entirely depends on the make and model of controller - there's no 'one answer fits all' for this one sorry.

Comment: I understood that when I asked it, but there are still answers conceivable that are helpful, and it's an issue that others potentially can run into as well. I was in doubt to ask such a general question, but still its presence would add knowledge, I concluded.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear to me, what you are asking about. I understand it two ways:
1. You ask if, when plugging in disks never before used with a controller to a controller that used to run an array in the past, would it try to flush battery/supercap backed caches to the new raid? It wouldn't, as there ain't an array yet, there.
2. Having a disk array for which controller died, replacing the controller with used one, will it try to flush any caches it has? Well, as mentioned previously, depends. Usually, with enterprise controllers, I'll expect it wouldn't. It would detect that its not the same array it used to serve, as disks would differ. BUT, depending on the maker and firmware, you may not even be able to swap broken controller, since it won't be able to recognize the array anyway.

Comment: The second scenario indeed. I would expect that too, but that's merely an assumption. Time to contact some support departments, perhaps.